# Rails adding error to :base not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have a double nested form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @item, html: { class: "create-item-form" } do |item_builder| %>
  <div class="well">
  <%= item_builder.input :name, required: false, error: false, label: "item name" %>
  <%= item_builder.input :description, as: :text, required: false, error: false, label: "How do users earn this item?" %>
  <%= item_builder.input :tag_list, required: false, label: "Tags (these will help users find your item)" %>

  <%= item_builder.simple_fields_for :user_items do |user_item_builder| %>
    <%= user_item_builder.input :foo, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: "bar" } %>

    <%= user_item_builder.simple_fields_for :user_item_images do |user_item_images_builder| %>
      <%= user_item_images_builder.input :foo, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: "bar" } %>
      <%= user_item_images_builder.input :picture, as: :file, required: false,
                error: false, label: "Pictures of you earning this item",
                input_html: { multiple: true,
                              name: "item[user_items_attributes][0][user_item_images_attributes][][picture]" } %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <%= item_builder.submit 'Submit new item request', class: "btn btn-primary pull-right inherit-width" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When a user doesn't upload a file for the `user_item_image` I need to display an error message.  I wrote a custom validation:

**user_item_image.rb**

```
class UserItemImage < ActiveRecord::Base

  include PicturesHelper

  attr_accessor :foo

  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  belongs_to :user_item
  validate :picture_size
  validate :has_picture

  private

  def has_picture
    errors.add(:base, 'You must include at least one picture.') if picture.blank?
  end
end
```

But I get the error message:

> User items user item images base You must include at least one picture.

How can I rewrite the validation so that it doesn't show the attribute and only shows the message.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
validates :picture, presence: true
```

on your `useritem` model

Comment: The :picture attribute is on my `user_item_images` model and not my `user_item` model