# Rails - Monkey-patch rails full_messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, monkeypatching

I've been having a tough time with rails error messages showing attributes when I don't it to ([Rails adding error to :base not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073676/rails-adding-error-to-base-not-working-as-expected/36074431#36074431)).

I found a site that monkey patches full messages so you can display error messages without showing the attribute http://adamhooper.com/eng/articles/5

However, this is quite old and rails has changed since then.  I'm wondering if it's possible to make the same monkey patch in rails 4.2.

The `full_messages` method was previously defined as:

```
...
    def full_messages(options = {})
      full_messages = [] 

      @errors.each_key do |attr|
        @errors[attr].each do |message|
          next unless message

          if attr == "base"
            full_messages << message
          else 
            attr_name = @base.class.human_attribute_name(attr)
            full_messages << attr_name + I18n.t('activerecord.errors.format.separator', :default => ' ') + message 
          end  
        end  
      end  
      full_messages
    end
```

and the patch:

```
if RAILS_GEM_VERSION =~ /^2\.3/
  ActiveRecord::Errors.class_eval do
    # Remove complicated logic
    def full_messages
      returning full_messages = [] do
        @errors.each_key do |attr|
          @errors[attr].each do |msg|
            full_messages << msg if msg 
          end 
        end 
      end 
    end 
  end 
end
```

The method is currently:

```
# File activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb, line 348
    def full_messages
      map { |attribute, message| full_message(attribute, message) }
    end

# File activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb, line 369
    def full_message(attribute, message)
      return message if attribute == :base
      attr_name = attribute.to_s.tr('.', '_').humanize
      attr_name = @base.class.human_attribute_name(attribute, :default => attr_name)
      I18n.t(:"errors.format", {
        :default   => "%{attribute} %{message}",
        :attribute => attr_name,
        :message   => message
      })
    end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why monkey patch it? Why not just create your own helper for displaying errors?

Comment: There are some forms I have where I have some fields where I want the attribute to show and some fields that I don't.

Comment: That does not answer the question, don't you think that it would better to create your own method rather than monkeypatch over the Rails method and risk breaking it on every update?

Comment: Yes I do think it would be better but I didn't think it would be possible to selectively choose when I want to display the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can also translate the field to have an empty string. Rails will find it in

```
en:
  activemodel:
    attributes:
      [CLASS_NAME]:
        [FIELD_NAME]: ''
```

And it won't show on the errors.